# Subscribe to an observable from HttpClient's GET method

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, observable, subscribe

I'm learning Angular and the course is outdated. I'm writing a very simple app which shows a list of people  created from `Persona` class which receives the parameters `nombre` and `apellido`.

The code is the following:

data.services.ts:

```
    cargarPersonas(){
        return this.httpClient.get('https://listado-personas-53faf-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/personas.json');
    }

    guardarPersonas(personas: Persona[]){
        this.httpClient.put('https://listado-personas-53faf-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/personas.json', personas).subscribe(
            response => alert(`Datos enviados correctamente: ${response}`),
            error => alert(`Error al enviar los datos: ${error}`)
        );
    }
```

persona.service.ts:

```
  setPersonas(personas: Persona[]){
    this.personas = personas;
  }

  obtenerPersonas(){
    return this.dataService.cargarPersonas();
  }

  agregarPersona(persona: Persona) {
    this.logginService.enviarMensajeAConsola('agregamos persona:' + persona.nombre);
    if(this.personas == null){
      this.personas = [];
    }
    this.personas.push(persona);
    this.dataService.guardarPersonas(this.personas);
  }
```

personas.component.ts:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.personasService.obtenerPersonas().subscribe(
      (personas: Persona[]) => {
        this.personas = personas;
        this.personasService.setPersonas(personas);
      }
    );
  }
```

By doing this I receive the error `No overload matches this call`.

Doing research I found that I should  modify the subscription on personas.component.ts as follows:

```
this.personasService.obtenerPersonas().subscribe(
      (personas: Object) => {
        this.personas = personas as Persona[];
        this.personasService.setPersonas(personas as Persona[]);
      }
    );
```

That solved the previous error, however now I get this another error: `NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed`.

When I do a `console.log()` of the object that I receive when I subscribe (`personas`) I can see that it's an object which contains an array (I left you an image of it at the end), but I don't know how to access to this array because when I try to iterate it I also get an error. When trying `Object.keys(personas)` I get a string with the name of the key and with `Objects.values(personas)` I get another object.

How can I work with the Persona's objects array that I get from Firebase?

[image: console.log(personas)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `cargarPersonas()` is not returning an `Observable<Persona[]>`, it's returning and http response object. In order to return the wanted type, you should change it to the following:

```
    cargarPersonas(){
        return this.httpClient.get<Persona[]>('https://listado-personas-53faf-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/personas.json');
    }
```

this also means you don't need to cast the argument:

```
this.personasService.obtenerPersonas().subscribe(
      (personas:Persona[]) => {
        this.personas = personas;
        this.personasService.setPersonas(personas);
      }
    );
```

An explanation of how it works can be found in [this](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response) doc

Comment: Excelent, it worked! You just should change the code after "Try this" because you forgot make the correction you say before. Thank you for solution and explanation!